# In an iphone app/ios, how to make a transparent 'loading' overlay that covers the nav bar and keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

In an iphone app/ios, how do i make a transparent 'loading' overlay that covers the navigation bar and keyboard?

I've tried the following but it doesn't cover either the nav bar nor the keyboard:

```
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5];
[self.view addSubview:overlay];
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't cover navbar because you need to add the subview to self.navigationController.view. There is a hierarchy of views, say 1: top bar 2: navbar 3: tab bar 4: your view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like a simple library that will take care of it, David Sinclair's **[DSActivityView](http://www.dejal.com/developer/dsactivityview)** is good.

Comment: Sounds good, but he needs credit if we use his code, and i'm not sure where in the app i can put credits!

Comment: @Chris When you submit your code you have the opportunity to modify the **Terms of Service** that are associated with your app. If you wish you can completely replace what Apple uses as the default, but I just leave the ToS that's in place and add credits and licenses associated with any libraries I use. In addition, on the app's website I add credits. Combined, those two cover it well, in my opinion, but even just the ToS modification should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

sometimes when I'm lazy to use other libraries I just do this:

```
// create a custom black view
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.view.frame];
overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
overlayView.alpha = 0.8;
overlayView.tag = 88;

// create a label
UILabel *message = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.view.frame];
[message setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:25.0f]];
message.text = @"message to my dear user";
message.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
message.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
message.tag = 99;

// and just add them to navigationbar view
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:message];
```

and then call a method that finds those views, fades them out and deletes them:

```
-(void) removeOverlayViews{
    UIView *view = (UIView *)[self.navigationController.view viewWithTag:88];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.navigationController.view viewWithTag:99];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
         animations:^{
             view.alpha = 0.0;
             label.alpha = 0.0;
         }
         completion:^(BOOL finished){
             [view removeFromSuperview];
             [label removeFromSuperview];
         }
     ];
}
```

sometimes I just want to show a message for a few seconds so I call this right after I add overlay views to navigationController:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeOverlayViews) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
```

Comment: You sir are the man, this is more of what stackoverflow needs to provide, not libraries when they are sooooooo unnecessary, people want to know how to do things that are this simple with ease, not a library, you made my night a lot easier thank you. From this I build my own custom spinner loading overlay ;)

Comment: agreed. more answers without referencing libraries, please! we should actually be teaching how to code not how to use pre-built stuff

Answer (score 2):

Add it to `self.view.window` instead. That may not cover the keyboard though. In which case you need to create your own window. Though this is not recommended by Apple. Which means: be careful and thorough in your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [DSActivityView](http://www.dejal.com/developer/dsactivityview).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Action sheet instead of a transparent view for loading :

```
actionSheetLoad = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading..Please wait" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheetLoading showInView:showInView];
```

The action sheet will overlay the entire view till the time background tasks(say fetching data from server/ hitting urls) are running.